# R, rnaturalearth and sf: remove a single border from map

Tags: r, maps, r-sf

Please consider the map in the reprex.
I do not want this to become political, but the bottom line is that I need the border between "Northern Cyprus"
"Cyprus" (you find them in ww_ini$name_long) to disappear. All the other borders in the map can stay.
Any idea about how to remove a single border in the map?
Many thanks!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.1, GDAL 2.4.0, PROJ 5.2.0



ww_ini <- ne_countries(scale = "medium",
                       type = 'map_units',
                       returnclass = "sf")






bb <- ne_download(type = "wgs84_bounding_box", category = "physical",
                  returnclass = "sf") 
#> OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
#> Source: "/tmp/RtmpH6Sa4R", layer: "ne_110m_wgs84_bounding_box"
#> with 1 features
#> It has 2 fields


gpl <-   ggplot(data = ww_ini) +
        geom_sf(  col = "black", lwd = 0.3 )+

        coord_sf(xlim=c(-20,45), ylim=c(30, 73) ) +
  theme_minimal()


gpl
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the following steps:

- decrease dimensions of your dataset / I expect that ISO code as a primary key could be enough (you can easily use it to join other data items back); the Natural Earth dataset has 64 columns, which kind of messes up with `summarise()` in the next step
- filter out the two Cypriot states - ISO codes "CYP" and "CYN" - and merge them into a single polygon via `dplyr::summarise()`
- filter out the "rest of the world" countries - ISO codes *not* in "CYP" and "CYN" - and bind them with the single Cypriot polygon

Sounds kind of complicated, may be easier to comprehend from code:

```
cyprus <- ww_ini %>% 
  select(sov_a3) %>% 
  filter(sov_a3 %in% c("CYP", "CYN")) %>% 
  mutate(sov_a3 = "PYC") %>%  # cyprus spelled backwards
  group_by(sov_a3) %>% 
  summarise()

map_src <- ww_ini %>% 
  select(sov_a3) %>% 
  filter(!sov_a3 %in% c("CYP", "CYN")) %>% 
  bind_rows(cyprus)


gpl <-   ggplot(data = map_src  ) +
  geom_sf(  col = "black", lwd = 0.3 )+
  
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-20,45), ylim=c(30, 73) ) +
  theme_minimal()


gpl
```

[image: map of europe with cyprus united]

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting that I can use group and summarize to merge countries. One question: when I download the naturalearth map, what is the different between type = 'map_units' and type = 'countries'?

Comment: As per natural earth: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-details/. Map units: (above) the four constituent countries of the United Kingdom – England, Wales, Scotland, and Northern Ireland.
Not usually useful but some FIPS and ISO codes refer to groups of individual admin-0 territories by these designations. US Pacific Island Territories, French Guiana, and more. PeakBagger has a good overview of dependencies.